Migration of Archived Files from IXOS (SAP Content Repository) to Azure Blob Storage
I’m working on migrating archived files from an external content repository (IXOS) to Azure Blob Storage. I have the following questions:

Can the data in IXOS be directly migrated as files (e.g., PDFs, TIFFs, etc.) to Azure Blob Storage, or does it need to be converted into binary format before migration?

If conversion to binary is necessary, what tools or methods would be recommended for this process?

Are there any considerations or best practices I should be aware of while performing this migration to ensure data integrity and compatibility with Azure Blob Storage?

Does Azure Blob Storage support metadata or tagging that could replace the existing metadata in IXOS? If yes, how can this mapping be performed effectively?


I’m looking for insights from anyone who has experience with similar migrations or expertise in SAP content repositories and Azure Blob Storage. Any code examples, tools, or detailed steps would be greatly appreciated.
